# Find the first zero in a bitarray

Tags: c, linux, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I have a bitmap

```
uint64_t bitmap[10000]
```

to keep track of the resources allocated in the system. 
Now the question is how do efficiently I find the first unset(zero) bit in this bitmap?

I am aware that there is `ffsll(unsigned long long)` in glibc for finding the first set bit, which I assume uses hardware instructions to do it.

To use this function in my case, first I need to initialize the array to set every bit to 1, then when I do the resource allocation, I have to linearly search the array for the first none zero word. then use ffsll() to find the first set bit.

How can I do it faster?

Update:
I am on a x86-64 cpu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can maintain a *tree* of bitmaps to efficiently find the lowest bit set. On a 64-bit CPU, you only have to have a tree depth of 3 to track 4096 64-bit elements -- that means only using three `ffsll` calls.

Basically, this works by dividing your array into 64-word chunks and assigning one 64-bit index to each chunk. A bit of the index word is set iff the corresponding bitset word has all bits set. When you change a bit in the bitset, you adjust the corresponding index word.

You can then build another index array on top to form a tree.

It requires a little extra work on every bit change, but the total amount of extra work (and storage) is negligible compared to the savings you get from not having to linearly search your bitset when you need a free bit.

Comment: thanks, I just thought that too, as bobshacks mentioned in his answer(dividing into chunks)

Comment: This gets complicated when you have the resource index that you want to deallocate but you need to find the exact chunk this corresponds to and then update the bitmap tree correspondingly. Furthermore dynamic growth of the bitmap tree has to use balancing techniques or else this bitmap tree will become unbalanced.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: For updating, it is very simple: break the index into 6-bit chunks, searching your tree using those chunk numbers from most- to least-significant. Unset the lowest bit; if the resulting 64-bit word is all-zeros, unset the corresponding in the parent, and so on. Balancing the tree is not necessary: each level is just a 64-way tree.

Comment: For example, the index 0b001011_110000_001100_010101 (0x2f0315) would resolve to successive bit-indices 11, 48, 12, 21. The design of this bitmap-tree is not unlike the multilevel page tables used to resolve addresses on x86 and other architectures.

Comment: I'm not dealing with a fixed size bitarray unlike the question. For a variable sized bitarray that can grow and shrink, I expect that this tree needs to be balanced as it's growing? In such a case how would this be done?

Comment: I feel like you could just expand your array by a factor of 64 each time that is needed, adding one level to your tree. You could allocate levels sparsely to avoid high memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd get much faster than this, but I'm open to being proven wrong:

```
uint64_t bitmap[10000];
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(bitmap) / sizeof(*bitmap)) && 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF == bitmap[i]; ++i);
const int bitInWord = ffsll(bitmap[i]);
const unsigned int firstZeroBit = bitInWord ? i * sizeof(*bitmap) * CHAR_BIT + bitInWord : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 32 bit cpu then you do not want to do that. Rather use arrays of 32 bit ints. The loop over the array will be faster.

Also you can encode every value for 1 byte and then pre-store which is the first bit set in the byte. So when you find an integer that is not all 0xFFFFFFFF you can then simply compare the bytes. If the first byte is not 0xFF then it is in that byte and so on.

So if a byte is not 0xFF it means it is one of the 255 possible values for the byte. And each value has a first bit set.

Another way of looking at the problem is to divide it up into chunks if possible. I do not know what your resource is so I cannot say.

Also consider that on the previous scan for the unset bit that it looped forward. If you store the index of the previous result, then you can simply start from the same index on the next search. Call this index the pos and use it each time.

You can also create a small array of "free" indexes each time you set a bit to zero, so when your "pos" reaches the end of the array just start again from one of the saved indexes.

In other words you really do not want to be running such a long loop each time. That is your problem, not the final instruction to get the bit. Use the index tracking as outlined above and it will go hundreds of times faster.